# PowerShell Windows Media Overlay

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, media

I am trying to get some information from windows in a powershell script.  I tried a lot of googling, but because of the vague terms its getting really messy.  So when you adjust your volume with a shortcut or volume control of any sort in Win10, that media overlay shows up in the corner.  It has the name of the audio currently playing, be it a youtube video, twitch stream or MP3 file.  I want to query windows for the name of whats play.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

A pointer? [SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.SystemMediaTransportControlsDisplayUpdater?view=winrt-19041)

You'll find a sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/dev/Samples/SystemMediaTransportControls).

I'm afraid this is not going to be of much use as it'll only tell you how to set the information.

I'd myself look into hooking, I've never tried hooking UWP calls platform-wide though.